# How to remove \x1b from a string in python

Tags: python, padding

I have a text file which contains a list of files.
I want to copy the files to certain location.

I have the following code

```
f= open("filename")
l = f.readline()
while l:
    cmd = "cp {0}/{1} {2}".format(indir,l.strip(),outdir)
    commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

Now when I read the file, each line is padded with `"\x1b[00m\x1b[00m"` on the left and `"\x1b[00m"` on the right. How do I get rid of this padding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are vt100 escape sequences. How did those get into the file in the first place?

Comment: re, is regular expressions for python.  You will probably want to use re.search("x1b",cmd)

Comment: I generated the file using the following command "ls patter*.txt > filename"

Comment: @Puneet Paul: Stupid Linux distributions dumbly aliasing `ls` so it colorizes output by default. Grr... Do this: `/bin/ls patter*.txt >filename`. The escape characters should disappear.

Comment: Your `ls` is colorizing the output. You must have `--color=always` set in an alias. Try adding `--color=none` to the `ls` command.

Comment: I got rid of the padding by doing a string.replace(l,'\x1b[00m',"")

Comment: thanks for the tip with colorizing. I will keep that in mind the next time i do that.

Comment: @Puneet Paul: I really do strongly suggest using the `shutil` module and `os.listdir` instead of using `ls` the way you are and feeding a `cp` command to a shell.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to make Python do this for you. I find it odd that you have VT100 escape sequences in your file. In comments you show the command you use to generate the file. I would suggest doing most of your file manipulation using the [shutil module](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)
 and the `os.listdir` function.

But, if you want to use `ls` to generate a list of filenames without bizarre escape sequences in them, do this:

```
/bin/ls patter*.txt >filename
```

This forces the shell to run the actual `ls` command instead of using whatever alias `ls` has been set to.